# EF Core child collections with same type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Given the following classes how do I get EF Core to map my two collections?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> BarWithTypeA { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> BarWithTypeB { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int BarType { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core does not let you do this (which was my first thought):

`_context.Foos.Inclue(x => x.BarWithTypeA.Where(w => w.BarType == 1);`

I've also tried adding a Global Query Filter without success. I'm sure it's simple but I'm at the point where I need a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your database layout, you don't have two links between `Foo` and `Bar`, there's only a single link, so your entity should match that:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

If you really want both of those properties, you could simulate them like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public List<Bar> BarWithTypeA => Bars.Where(b => b.BarType == 1);
[NotMapped]
public List<Bar> BarWithTypeB => Bars.Where(b => b.BarType == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way to do this in SQL land. You could have two optional FooIds on your Bar class for each type:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public int? FooIdWhenTypeA { get; set; }
    public int? FooIdWhenTypeB { get; set; }
    public int BarType { get; set; }
}
```

But what I recommend is actually disambiguating this on the client side:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Bar> BarWithTypeA { get => Bars.Where(x => x.BarType == 1).ToList() }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Bar> BarWithTypeB { get => Bars.Where(x => x.BarType == 2).ToList() }
}
```